# Create a new Card using onPressed()

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

When the user clicks the FAB, i want it to create a new `Card` widget wrapped in a `GestureDetector`. I have created a list of type widget and also created a function with a `setState` to add to the list and display it in a `SliverGrid`. but when i click the FAB, it doesnt seem to be adding.

Could i get a small guide on how to add a `Card` using an FAB. (or adding any type of widget in a `SliverGrid`).

the list : `List<Widget> cardList = <Widget>[];`

function for adding items to the list :

```
void addItems() async{
  setState(() {
    cardList.insert(0, GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        await Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => TodoList(), // this just navigates to another screen ; not important in this question
        )
        );
      },
      child: Card(

          child:Center(child: whitefontstylemont(text: "project 1", size:20,)) //this is just a custom TextStyle
      ),
    ));
  });
}
```

the floating action button which adds a new Card to the list :

```
floatingActionButton:  FloatingActionButton( // this is inside a Scaffold
  onPressed: ()async {
    setState(() {
addItems();
    });
  },
  heroTag: "btn2",
  child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Color(whitecolor),), backgroundColor: Color(redcolor),),
```

the `SliverGrid` where i want a new card to be displayed :

```
SliverGrid(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2
  ),
  delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
      return cardList[index];
    },
    childCount: cardList.length // this is where i want a new Card to be displayed
  )
),
```

Comment: First thing I would do is to not save Widgets in your State. In your case you can simply save the current number of cards in the screen, so just put an `int cardCount` in your State. Then build your cards in the SliverGrid

Comment: Hey @Martyns! Sorry i am a bit new to flutter (and app development); could you just clarify on how i can use an ```int cardCount``` in the ```setState```? and how do i map it to the list ```cardList```?

Comment: Flutter needs to rebuild the widgets everytime you call setState. If you just save the Widget objects in a list in the State, those will not get rebuilt. When you press a button you can do `setState(() { cardCount += 1; })`  Then, in the build method you can use a for loop to generate the list of Card widgets using that cardCount int

Comment: I was able to generate a new ```Card``` using your ```setState``` method but it does seem to save the created cards when i reopen or hot restart the app. Could you please suggest me a method on how to save it when the app reopens?

Comment: You need to look at some persistent storage alternatives (Shared preferences, sqflite...)

Answer (score 0):

You can add Cards in your List by tracking the number of Cards intended to be in the List by setting an `int cardCount`. The initial cardCount can be defined inside `initState()` for example. Then update the cardCount inside **setState()** to rebuild the screen with the Widget.